# Publish Failing for pages in Tridion 2013 in "Committing Deploy" phase

Tags: 2013

[image]

My page contains four components. All the components are more or less similar. The first three components is working fine and the last component creating the issue.
I checked the Component template and its TBB everything is fine but due to this component only the page is getting failed at the Committing Deployment stage kindly help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you please share the deployer logs? That will provide insight into what is happening.

Comment: And the deployer and storage configuration also as we'll very likely want to see these next...

Answer (score 1):

Given the age of this question I'm hoping you've already figured out your issue, but, for the sake of anyone who finds this question with the same issue in the future, I wanted to highlight the cause that I have found to be the most common in my experience.

Duplicate binaries, as mentioned by Raj, are a fairly common issue arising from situations where two different binary items in Tridion share a file name and are being published from the same publication. Since Tridion attempts to place all files into the same folder on the file system by default in many implementations there will obviously be a unique filename conflict with the second binary. I wouldn't be surprised if the component blocking publishing in this case contains a duplicate binary. The deployer logs would show this pretty clearly. There are ways to get around this programmatically if you're running into the issue repeatedly, but the simplest solution is to just make sure all binary filenames are unique.

For more detail you can check out Chris Summers' comprehensive blog post [here](http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/unique-binary-filenames-for-sdl-tridion-multimedia-components.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Hiren, Bj0rn. do check the logs in debug/verbose mode. also check following in respect to  problematic component

- Write Permission on the all the folders are correct, images, binary and other folders
- Duplicate binary already exists in respective folder.
- Paths in storage config
- Check JDK version
- check any hotfix available for this error if any